# Why does the annotation test environment of UIMA-Ruta count some annotations as True Positive and False Positiv

Tags: uima, ruta

I would like to evaluate my ruta script using the annotation test environment provided by the uima ruta plugin for eclipse. I've built a manually-annotated corpus. Some annotations are evaluated as true postives as well as false positives, which should not be possible per definition.

I have already checked, if there are minor differences between the true positives and false positives, but they are in fact identical (same offsets).

As an option I chose "partial match".

When I check the results.xmi, where I can see the true positives, false positives, and false negatives as annotations, the annotations in question have an error-feature; but there is no further information.

[True Postives and False Positives as Annotations in the result.xmi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdWk6.png)

The annotations in question should actually be true positives.

Edit: I also noticed that when I specify only one type (i.e. one type of annotation) to be evaluated, everything is like it should be. The problem occurs only when more than one type is supposed to be evaluated.

Comment: I have this issue too. I created test file (.xmi) by copying the .xmi file generated by the ruta script file (that is, no manual intervention). Now when I run the test and inspect the *.result.xmi file, I notice that some (not all!) annotations have been duplicated, though in the source xmi they appear only once. This explains False Positives. Unclear, why the duplicates have been generated.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Do you have an alternative to evaluate ruta scipts?

Comment: My best guess is that you have overlapping annotations where the second candidate is counted as false positive because another already "consumed" the true positive one. The partial matching is rather lax. Can you provide a minimal example for reproducing the behavior or a description for creating such an example?

Comment: What are the other settings? Is all types activated?